# Could not initialize class org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults

Tags: spring, java-8, weblogic

I am migrating maven multi module project from `spring 3.2.9` to `4.3.4` version, after upgrade getting the following exception in weblogic log

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
Could not initialize class
org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults    at
weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
```

Following Versions I am using in my application :

> Java : 1.8.0_102, Spring : 4.3.4, Weblogic server : 1221.1

Comment: Is `spring-beans` on the classpath?

Comment: Yes it is on classpath